# I am having problem converting py file to exe with ultralytics library = 8.1.20

Tags: python, auto-py-to-exe, ultralytics

> ## [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjnAa.jpg)  Can someone help me
>
> ```
>  File "ultralytics\utils\__init__.py", line 271, in <module>
>   File "ultralytics\utils\__init__.py", line 238, in set_logging
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encoding'
> ```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors